# Add audios according to their timestamps with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i first.mka -i second.mka -i third.mka -i fourth.mka
       -filter_complex
         "[1]adelay=184000|184000[b];
          [2]adelay=360000|360000[c];
          [3]adelay=962000|962000[d];
          [0][b][c][d]amix=4"
merged.mka
```

But it turned out that `amix` scales each input's volume by `1/n` where `n` = no. of active inputs. A normalization workaround is unacceptable in my case because I have hundreds of inputs. Is the any alternative way to add audio files according to their timestamps?

Comment: Why is the workaround unacceptable?

Comment: My audio files have different audio volume and they must have different volume after this command. I'd like to keep the quality of my files and do not use unnecessary transformations.

Comment: It's ok to place every next file "on top" if it overlaps the previous file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [acrossfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade) with `nofade` curve, for example:

```
ffmpeg -i first.mka -i second.mka -i third.mka -i fourth.mka -filter_complex "
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=5:c1=nofade:c2=nofade[1x];
[1x][2:a]acrossfade=d=5:c1=nofade:c2=nofade[2x];
[2x][3:a]acrossfade=d=5:c1=nofade:c2=nofade[a]
" -map [a] -c:a aac -q:a 4 -y /tmp/output.mka
```

change duration=5 with yours for every audio (begin of second audio timestamp minus end of first audio timestamp). the problem occurs if the third file overlaps the first ☹

Comment: It outputs 1KB file and writes `size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[aac @ 00000233de4c3f40] Qavg: nan`. When I tried `-c:a pcm_f32le out.wav` I got `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`.

Comment: @user14706760 I'm sorry. I forgot rename vars

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

Comment: @user14706760 try it with two files: `ffmpeg -i first.mka -i second.mka -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=5:c1=nofade:c2=nofade" -y /tmp/output.mka`

Comment: It does not work: `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded`